# Finding Specified Object Index in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code :

```
var items = [{ value: 1, text: "one" }, { value: 2, text: "two" }, { value: 3, text: "three" }];
console.log(items.indexOf({ value: 2, text: "two" }));
```

And i get this result in console :

```
-1
```

But I expect to get the object index, what should I do?

Comment: Unfortunately `Array.indexOf` doesn't work that way, mostly because two objects are never the same.

Comment: It wont work because if the strict comparison being used.

Comment: Downvoter please leave comment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript's `Array.indexOf` does not compare the properties of the objects. It just [uses `===` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). And the `===` operator won't consider the object you are creating in the second line equal to the one you've got in the `items` array simply because they are two different objects.

Maybe this will help you:

```
if ({"a":1} === {"a":1}) alert("equal"); else alert("not equal");
```

The two objects are not equal. So the only solution would be to iterate on all items of the array and compare each one's properties to your new object (provided in tymeJV's answer).

There is also a built-in [`findIndex` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) only in firefox that makes this task easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate and check:

```
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].value == 2 && items[i].text == "two") {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(index);
```

Comment: Seems correct to me too. I even referenced it in my answer!

Answer (score -1):

A little tricky, but it could help you: [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A6BD4/).

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObj = function(obj) {    
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(JSON.stringify(this[i]) == JSON.stringify(obj)) {
            return i;   
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(items.indexOfObj({ value: 2, text: "two" }));
```

Comment: Keep in mind this assumes the properties are in the same order of the object passed in and the object being checked (also keep in mind objects are unordered)

Comment: @tymeJV, yeah, thank you, i forgot about it. Looks like isn't really safe solution.